# Installing Ruby 2.0.0p0 on Mountain Lion: Error running 'make -j8'

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0 via RVM (`rvm install 2.0.0`) on my Mac with Mountain Lion. Everything seems to go smoothly until the end where it states `Error running 'make -j8'`. I'm using XCode 4.6.2 as well. How do I fix it?

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
######################################################################## 100.0%
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling...............................................................................................................................................................................................................
Error running 'make -j8',
please read /Users/scott/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1368502313_make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The last 100 lines of the above make.log file:

```
new-host-6:ruby-2.0.0-p0 scott$ tail -100 1368502313_make.log 
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/erb.rb:341:in `<class:ERB>'
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/erb.rb:354:in `<class:Compiler>'
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/erb.rb:375:in `<class:Scanner>'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   miniruby                            0x0000000100542e54 rb_vm_bugreport + 164
1   miniruby                            0x000000010041a16e report_bug + 302
2   miniruby                            0x000000010041a424 rb_bug + 180
3   miniruby                            0x0000000100538ed0 vm_exec_core + 32080
4   miniruby                            0x00000001005390ae vm_exec + 94
5   miniruby                            0x0000000100539f8a rb_iseq_eval + 266
6   miniruby                            0x000000010041ed82 rb_load_internal + 306
7   miniruby                            0x00000001004204d1 rb_require_safe + 1313
8   miniruby                            0x0000000100528c94 call_cfunc_1 + 20
9   miniruby                            0x000000010052f156 vm_call_cfunc + 1046
10  miniruby                            0x000000010053dd10 vm_call_method + 224
11  miniruby                            0x0000000100534393 vm_exec_core + 12819
12  miniruby                            0x00000001005390ae vm_exec + 94
13  miniruby                            0x0000000100539e5e rb_iseq_eval_main + 206
14  miniruby                            0x000000010041d4ef ruby_exec_internal + 111
15  miniruby                            0x000000010041e4d2 ruby_run_node + 82
16  miniruby                            0x00000001003e45ef main + 79
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ee217e1 start + 0
18  ???                                 0x000000000000000b 0x0 + 11

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./tool/generic_erb.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/cgi/util.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111: [BUG] Stack consistency error (sp: 38, bp: 36)
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0006 p:0038 s:0038 e:000037 CLASS  /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111
c:0005 p:0035 s:0034 e:000033 CLASS  /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:107
c:0004 p:0009 s:0032 e:000031 TOP    /Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:85 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0030 e:000029 CFUNC  :require
c:0002 p:0098 s:0026 E:000488 EVAL   ./tool/mkconfig.rb:11 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0018b8 TOP    [FINISH]

./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in `<main>'
./tool/mkconfig.rb:11:in `require'
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:85:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:107:in `<module:FileUtils>'
/Users/scott/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/fileutils.rb:111:in `<module:NoWrite>'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   miniruby                            0x0000000109ffbe54 rb_vm_bugreport + 164
1   miniruby                            0x0000000109ed316e report_bug + 302
2   miniruby                            0x0000000109ed3424 rb_bug + 180
3   miniruby                            0x0000000109ff1ed0 vm_exec_core + 32080
4   miniruby                            0x0000000109ff20ae vm_exec + 94
5   miniruby                            0x0000000109ff2f8a rb_iseq_eval + 266
6   miniruby                            0x0000000109ed7d82 rb_load_internal + 306
7   miniruby                            0x0000000109ed94d1 rb_require_safe + 1313
8   miniruby                            0x0000000109fe1c94 call_cfunc_1 + 20
9   miniruby                            0x0000000109fe8156 vm_call_cfunc + 1046
10  miniruby                            0x0000000109ff6d10 vm_call_method + 224
11  miniruby                            0x0000000109fed393 vm_exec_core + 12819
12  miniruby                            0x0000000109ff20ae vm_exec + 94
13  miniruby                            0x0000000109ff2e5e rb_iseq_eval_main + 206
14  miniruby                            0x0000000109ed64ef ruby_exec_internal + 111
15  miniruby                            0x0000000109ed74d2 ruby_run_node + 82
16  miniruby                            0x0000000109e9d5ef main + 79
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ee217e1 start + 0

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./tool/mkconfig.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

make: *** [encdb.h] Abort trap: 6
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: is command line tools from Xcode installed?

Comment: Yes, I had no problems install Ruby 1.9.3 a while ago.

Comment: Check to make sure you are not using the CLANG Xcode compiler.  It causes unusual bugs like this.  There are many questions on this site about CLANG incompatibilities.

Comment: what version of RVM do you use? make sure to try `1.20.7`

Comment: @MichaelPapile - how do I make sure I'm not using CLANG?

Comment: @mpapis - I was using 1.20.5, just upgraded to 1.20.7 with `rvm get stable --auto`. Just noticed Ruby 2.0.0p195 came out today too! Now it all works!!! Don't know if it was the latest version of rvm or ruby... Put your comment down as an answer and I'll credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed in recent ruby release `2.0.0-p195` which was released with RVM `1.20.7` just few minutes ago.